# Rgooglemaps PlotOnStaticMap Not Scaling with GetMap SCALE parameter

Tags: r, plot, scaletransform, rgooglemaps

I'm trying to plot some GPS points using [Rgooglemaps](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RgoogleMaps/versions/1.4.2) and to create a plot image larger than 640x640px.

Rgooglemaps [GetMap](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RgoogleMaps/versions/1.4.2/topics/GetMap) has a `SCALE` parameter which scales the retrieved google map by up to a factor of two.

Examples: [No Scaling](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.6976633,-74.1201072&zoom=10&scale=1&size=640x640&maptype=roadmap) & [Scaled by 2](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=40.6976633,-74.1201072&zoom=10&scale=2&size=640x640&maptype=roadmap)

***Note:*** The URLs above work intermittently, as Google limits the number of requests allowed without supplying an API key. Just mash F5 until it loads.

If the `SCALE` value is anything other than 1 in R, when I plot my data with [PlotOnStaticMap](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/RgoogleMaps/versions/1.4.2/topics/PlotOnStaticMap), none of my coordinates align properly with the map (the map is scaled up, the points are not).

I realise I can scale the output up by avoiding the `SCALE` and specifying:

`png('map.png', height=1280, width=1280)`

But this extrapolates the default 640x640px image and the result is blurry.

Is there a way to also proportionally scale up a table of coordinates?

Comment: You'll likely get better and faster answers if you could provide some code (i.e. a reproducible example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out no scaling of the coordinates was needed, just a few extra parameters:-

What I should've been doing:

```
# Load Library
library(RgoogleMaps)

# Sample Coordinates
latCoord <- c(40.7079865,40.7062643,40.7043945)
lonCoord <- c(-73.9991936,-73.9969399, -73.9946165)
center <- c(40.707034,-73.992721)

maptile <- GetMap(center=center, zoom=16, maptype='roadmap', extraURL = "&scale=2")

png('testmap.png', height=1280, width=1280)
PlotOnStaticMap(maptile, lat = latCoord, lon = lonCoord, pch = 19, col = "black", add=FALSE, TrueProj = TRUE, cex = 2, size = c(640, 640))
```

Note the `size` parameter in the `PlotOnStaticMap` function needs to be set to 640x640px, even though the output is double that.